# OpenCV in Flutter

Tags: flutter, opencv, dart

I am working on a project using OpenCV. I already created a python "prototype". Now I'd like to move it to Flutter. This is where I encountered a few problems.
I imported the https://pub.dev/packages/opencv flutter package.

```dart
import "package:opencv/opencv.dart";
import 'package:opencv/core/core.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';


Future<void> main() async {
  var url = "/sdcard/Download/test5.png";
  var myFile = await File(url).readAsBytes();
  print(myFile);
  print(await ImgProc.medianBlur(myFile, 5));
}
```

After I run this code I get this error:

```dart
E/flutter (10044): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (10044): #0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:142:86)
E/flutter (10044): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:148:36)
E/flutter (10044): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:331:12)
E/flutter (10044): #3      ImgProc.medianBlur (package:opencv/core/imgproc.dart:539:43)
E/flutter (10044): #4      main (package:projectgama/opencvTest.dart:19:23)
E/flutter (10044): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10044):
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Did anybody manage to work with OpenCV in Flutter?

Comment: can you add some more code to better understanding?

Comment: This is all I'm using right now. This was just supposed to be a minimal test.

Comment: Then first download the package's repo example and run it and test it.

Comment: I did that, but it gave me an error.

Comment: Did you try your code on iOS? This package actually just supports android "iOS not supported currently - I do not own a Mac, so deploying for iOS will be a little slow.
" | btw. this package isn´t null safety